After runing the stored procedure, I am getting an error
I am getting "STATEMENT_ERROR" after execution of this stored procedure.
I am trying to insert json data into my snowflake table:
CREATE SEQUENCE order_id_seq --START = 0 INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    order_id NUMBER default order_id_seq.nextval,
    customer_id VARCHAR(10),
    order_date DATE,
    total_amount FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

-- Create the product table
CREATE TABLE products 
(
    order_id NUMBER ,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    quantity INT,
    unit_price FLOAT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_order_and_products(json_data VARIANT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    order_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Step 1: Insert data into the orders table
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_date, total_amount)
    SELECT
        json_data:customer_id::VARCHAR(50) AS customer_id,
        TO_DATE(json_data:order_date::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS order_date,
        json_data:total_amount::FLOAT AS total_amount;

    -- Step 2: Get the order_id of the recently inserted order
    order_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();

    -- Step 3: Insert data into the products table
    INSERT INTO products (order_id, product_name, quantity, unit_price)
    SELECT
        order_id AS order_id,
        product.value:name::VARCHAR(50) AS product_name,
        product.value:quantity::INTEGER AS quantity,
        product.value:unit_price::FLOAT AS unit_price
    FROM
        (SELECT FLATTEN(json_data:products)) AS product;

    RETURN 'Data inserted successfully.';

END;
$$;


CALL insert_order_and_products(parse_json('{
    "customer_id": "C001",
    "order_date": "2024-04-26",
    "total_amount": 100.50,
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Product A",
            "quantity": 2,
            "unit_price": 25.25
        },
        {
            "name": "Product B",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_price": 50.00
        }
    ]
}'));


Hi - please format your code as code, so that it is readable. Thanks

What is LAST_INSERT_ID()?

There are multiple issues in your code:

There is no such function as LAST_INSERT_ID() in Snowflake. The similar one is LAST_QUERY_ID(), however, it returned last ran query ID, not the insert ID of the primary key column.

You can get the last insert ID by querying the table as below:
select order_id into :order_id from orders order by order_id desc limit 1;


There is no column named product_name, the column name is "name"

To access the variable JSON_DATA, you need to add ":" prefix, otherwise the compiler won't be able to know if it is an identifier or a variable. So you need to change the following query from:


    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_date, total_amount)
    SELECT
        json_data:customer_id::VARCHAR(50) AS customer_id,
        TO_DATE(json_data:order_date::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS order_date,
        json_data:total_amount::FLOAT AS total_amount;

to
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_date, total_amount)
    SELECT
        :json_data:customer_id::VARCHAR(50) AS customer_id,
        TO_DATE(:json_data:order_date::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS order_date,
        :json_data:total_amount::FLOAT AS total_amount;


The following query is not correct in the SQL SP:

    SELECT
        order_id AS order_id,
        product.value:name::VARCHAR(50) AS product_name,
        product.value:quantity::INTEGER AS quantity,
        product.value:unit_price::FLOAT AS unit_price
    FROM
        (SELECT FLATTEN(json_data:products)) AS product;

The correct way is:
    SELECT
        :order_id AS order_id,
        product.value:name::VARCHAR(50) AS name,
        product.value:quantity::INTEGER AS quantity,
        product.value:unit_price::FLOAT AS unit_price
    FROM
        (SELECT * from table(FLATTEN(input => :json_data:products))) AS product;

To put them together, the full code as below:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_order_and_products(json_data VARIANT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    order_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Step 1: Insert data into the orders table
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_date, total_amount)
    SELECT
        :json_data:customer_id::VARCHAR(50) AS customer_id,
        TO_DATE(:json_data:order_date::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS order_date,
        :json_data:total_amount::FLOAT AS total_amount;

    -- Step 2: Get the order_id of the recently inserted order
    -- order_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    select order_id into :order_id from orders order by order_id desc limit 1;

    -- return :order_id;

    -- Step 3: Insert data into the products table
    INSERT INTO products (order_id, name, quantity, unit_price)
    SELECT
        :order_id AS order_id,
        product.value:name::VARCHAR(50) AS name,
        product.value:quantity::INTEGER AS quantity,
        product.value:unit_price::FLOAT AS unit_price
    FROM
        (SELECT * from table(FLATTEN(input => :json_data:products))) AS product;

    RETURN 'Data inserted successfully.';

END
;

